# Do I need a special microUSB cable to take advantage of my USB 3.0 port?

Tags: usb, cable, usb-3, data-transfer

I often transfer files from my computer to my phone using a micro-USB cable. However, my computer has USB 3.0 ports and I don't know if I'm taking full advantage of it using a regular micro-USB cable. Will any micro-USB cable make use of the full theoretical data transfer speeds of USB 3.0? Will my phone charge faster because of the 1 A output in USB 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3.0 data transfer speed, you need:

1. both sides support 3.0
2. A cable that support 3.0 (with extra USB 3.0 wire pairs).
       For instance, Samsung Galaxy Note 3 USB cable supports USB 3.0:
   [image: Note 3]

For the battery charge, it depend on your phone battery management chip limitation. if you chip only support 0.5A charging current, there will be no difference when using a 1A power source.